# move every second and third row into new columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm scraping the 'ranking' table off of a website. The way the table is structured, the team, grand slam points, and overall points end up in the same column when scraped. I've tried the below, and it looks somewhat correct except the last row. It took the values of the first row and put them in the last row, but in the wrong place.

I actually have two questions. The first is, what should I do to fix this? The second is, I will be creating a loop to scrape this same table off of over 50 pages from this website. Is the structure I have below even acceptable for a loop?

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
Url = read_html('http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053150')

tgo2 = Url %>% 
  html_nodes('td') %>% 
  html_text()

tgo2 = data.frame(tgo2)

t = as.data.frame(matrix(tgo2$tgo2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
```

Comment: I am unable to get your code to run after loading the packages I think you're using. What packages are you using?

Comment: sorry! tidyverse and rvest. let me add those in

Comment: It looks like tgo2 is returning 49 rows of data (not a multiple of 3).  The last row is blank, so if remove the last row, you will be good to go.

Comment: how would I incorporate that into a loop? I need to scrape the table from several other pages on this website.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this without deleting the last row?

Comment: You need to make sure that the number of rows in tgo2 is a multiple of 3, so for the above page either delete the last row or add 2 more blank rows.

Comment: Yep, c(tgo2$tgo2,'','') instead of just tgo2$tgo2 in the last line seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
Url <- read_html("http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053150")

tgo2 <- Url %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>%
  html_text()

(tgo2 <- tibble(tgo2) |> mutate(
  rn = row_number(),
  grp3 = rn %% 3,
  rgrp = cumsum(grp3 == 1)
))

(result <- pivot_wider(tgo2,
                       names_from = "grp3",
                       values_from = "tgo2") |>
  fill(-rn, .direction = "down") |>
  group_by(rgrp) |>
  filter(rn == max(rn)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-(1:2)))
```